# Are unprotected mysql queries always a concern?

Tags: php, mysql, code-injection

Right now I'm using a mysql query to check if a user exists and if so redirect the page.  Nothing is being echo'd out, and the redirect doesn't involved any data from the query.  I can't fathom where there could be any risk, so I just want to make sure there's not something I don't understand.  Thanks!

```
if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM performers WHERE username='".$_GET['username']."' AND acct_type='group'")) > 0) {
        header('Location: gprofile.php?username='.$_GET['username']);
        exit();
    }
```

Comment: Unless somebody dropping your entire database before getting all the info of your users isn't a concern to you... yeah it's always a concern

Comment: `yourWebPage.com/?username=' OR 1=1; DELETE FROM performers;--` etc etc

Comment: Points taken.  I suppose I didn't think about the possibility of deletion...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, definitely a concern. If a hacker decided their username was `bob';drop table performers;--` then you're in trouble.

ALWAYS **ALWAYS** use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) on untrusted data (or to be safe, any data).

Comment: http://xkcd.com/327/ related.

Comment: @Tomás yeah that's a good one :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition the glaring SQL injection vulnerability (described already by DuncanNZ) there is a CSRF vulnerability too.